# SiteEdit 2009 SP3 - Anchor Links not working

Tags: 2011, siteedit-2009

We've got a page on our site where we have some defined anchor links to certain portions of the page (cutting edge stuff I know ;-) )

```
www.foo.com/team/default.aspx#person1
```

However we're seeing some odd behavior when using Site Edit 2009 SP3. Lets say our original url is something like this:

```
www.foo.com/SiteEdit/#/team/default.aspx
```

When we click on one of our anchor links we're seeing the URL be changed to this:

```
www.foo.com/SiteEdit/#/#person1
```

We applied Hot Fix SE_2.3.0.76375 - Cumulative Hotfix since it had reference to correcting an issue with query string values, but to no avail. Any suggestions welcome

Comment: Are those urls in the browser or in the (SE) markup? Not sure if it's related, but the documentation mentions by default SiteEdit will try to open anchors in a new window (adding `target="_self"` should prevent this).

Comment: Have you verified that this isn't a browser issue? As in, does it all work perfectly when you are not using SiteEdit? If so, it looks like a defect - most likely related to the use of forward-slashes in the hashtag (which might be confused as part of the base URL)

Comment: With site edit turned off/disabled the links work fine, its only with site edit turned on. At this point we're scrapping site edit on our side and trying to switch to experience manager, since we've run into a number of issues with the Site Edit 2009 SP3 platform